# Is there a way to detect if an Apple Watch is paired with an iPhone?

Tags: ios, iphone, apple-watch

I want to know if there's an API available that shows the availability of an Apple Watch. I don't want to write an Apple Watch App yet. I want to do some analysis to see what percentage of actual users have an Apple Watch, before investing time to develop a watch version (if possible, of course).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Swift 5**

```
import WatchConnectivity
```

Then:

```
final class WatchSessionManager: NSObject {

    private override init() {}

    static let shared = WatchSessionManager()

    func setup() {
        guard WCSession.isSupported() else {
            return
        }
        let session = WCSession.default
        session.delegate = self
        session.activate()
    }
}

extension WatchSessionManager: WCSessionDelegate {

    func sessionDidBecomeInactive(_ session: WCSession) {}

    func sessionDidDeactivate(_ session: WCSession) {}

    func session(
        _ session: WCSession, 
        activationDidCompleteWith activationState: WCSessionActivationState, 
        error: Error?
    ) {
        print("Apple Watch is paired: \(session.isPaired)")
    }

}
```

Answer (score 6):

So on WatchOS 2 that is possible !

You have to do on iPhone side :

First :

```
import WatchConnectivity
```

Then :

```
   if WCSession.isSupported() { // check if the device support to handle an Apple Watch
        let session = WCSession.defaultSession()
        session.delegate = self
        session.activateSession() // activate the session

        if session.paired { // Check if the iPhone is paired with the Apple Watch
                // Do stuff
        }
    }
```

I hope It would help you :)

Comment: As of iOS 9.3 you must wait for `session(_:activationDidCompleteWith:error:)` to be called on the delegate before you can get a reliable value from `session.paired`

Answer (score 4):

The answer is yes but you have to support watchOS 2 and iOS9 to do it. 
You need to check the property `paired`from `WCSession` class.

You can find all the information at [Watch Connectivity Framework Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/WatchConnectivity/Reference/WCSession_class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/WCSession/watchAppInstalled). I also recommend to watch this video from [WWDC 2015](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2015/?id=713) and read this [tutorial](http://ymedialabs.github.io/blog/2015/07/03/communication-in-apple-watchos-2/)